# Getting the binary content of a BLOB

Tags: javascript, binary, blob

I know that, in order to convert a BLOB object to a readable format (URL) in Javascript, I should use the createObjectURL() method, right ?

**Example :**

```
var blob = new Blob(["Example"], { type: "text/plain" });
url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

**My question is:**

Is it possible to get the **raw binary** content of a BLOB ? so, I can get something like :

```
"01000101 01111000 01100001 01101101 01110000 01101100 01100101" // "Example" in binary .
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Convert the `blob` to an `ArrayBuffer` (see 2 methods). Create an ArrayBufferView (Int8array in this case), spread it into an array, and then map the view to the binary representation of each number using Number.toString() with a radix of 2 - `.toString(2)`.

**Method 1** - Use the [`Blob.arrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer) instance method to get a promise that resolves with the `ArrayBuffer`:

```js
const blobToBinary = async (blob) => {
  const buffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
  
  const view = new Int8Array(buffer);
  
  return [...view].map((n) => n.toString(2)).join(' ');
};

const blob = new Blob(["Example"], { type: "text/plain" });

blobToBinary(blob).then(console.log);
```

**Method 2** - [Extract the data from the blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#Example_for_extracting_data_from_a_Blob) using a [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader). To get an ArrayBuffer use [`FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer).

```js
const blob = new Blob(["Example"], { type: "text/plain" });

const reader = new FileReader();

reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {  
  const view = new Int8Array(reader.result);
  
  const bin = [...view].map((n) => n.toString(2)).join(' ');
  
  console.log(bin);
});

reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

Comment: Thank you, I've been fighting with getting fetched data from JS in blob form to C# `byte[]` for the last 2 days and your use of a view allowed me to make some progress. Do you know how I can perform this data transformation in C#? My blob's are passed via WebSocket and read via `MemoryStream`

Comment: Welcome. Unfortunately, I Can't help you with C#.

Comment: for anyone reading Blob actually has arrayBuffer built-in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer

Comment: @ihorbond - thanks. I've updated the answer.

Comment: hey @OriDrori do you know if this would still work in the case of video ? I'm trying to serialize blob into a string to pass it from front(puppeteer) to backend(nodejs) and then write it into a file. No matter what I try the file ends up corrupted :(

Comment: I don't have any experience with that. Create a question in SO. I'll try playing with it a bit anyway.

Comment: The code should use Uint8Array instead of Int8Array. Otherwise you may get negative signs in the output.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a FileReader to get the contents of the BLOB as a byte array:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
reader.onloadend = (event) => {
    // The contents of the BLOB are in reader.result:
    console.log(reader.result);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#Example_for_extracting_data_from_a_Blob

Comment: Thank you @MátéSafranka , so there is no way to access the raw binary from the BLOB it self, right ?

Comment: Not that I've ever heard of, no.