# Convert chunks of Blob to video in real-time

Tags: javascript, video, stream, webrtc, rtmp

I have a client that stream your cam to blobs that send to an socket.io to another client. But I have strugglying to show this blobs in real-time in this client. Let's see the code:

```
<video id="video"></video>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    const socket = io('/');
    const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
    const video = document.getElementById("video");
    const arrayOfBlobs = [];
    video.src = url;

    socket.on('stream', blob => {
        console.log(blob);
        arrayOfBlobs.push(blob);
        appendToSourceBuffer();
    });

    let sourceBuffer = null;
    mediaSource.addEventListener("sourceopen", () => {
        sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer("video/webm; codecs=\"opus,vp8\"");
        sourceBuffer.addEventListener("updateend", appendToSourceBuffer);
    });

    function appendToSourceBuffer() {
        if (
            mediaSource.readyState === "open" &&
            sourceBuffer &&
            sourceBuffer.updating === false
        ) {
            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(arrayOfBlobs.shift());
        }
    }
</script>
```

Basically I tried to get the blobs that I receive from the socket.io and convert to source buffer for make an append to the tag video on html, but noting happens. All blobs came perfectly but I think that I need to make some tratative before....

Anyone? Thanks!

Comment: Is this solved now? I think you need to append actual binary data stored in some Array (not just feed in some array of multiple Blob objects). You can use **FileReader** API to  extract binary from a blob, so your `arrayOfBlobs.push(blob);` really should be `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);` where the binary is then found at its `onloadend` event using `arrayOfBlobs.push( new Uint8Array( reader.result ) );` ... See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49653518/2057709

Comment: No, I no resolved yet.... I can get the binary from the blob but I can't put it inside the video tag, it doesn't render